# Mi consulta de eloquent no me trae todos los registros en mi tabla

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sql-server, eloquent

Tengo un proyecto que tiene conexiónes a distintas bases de datos en SQL Server y MySQL.
Ya logré hacer la conexión con las distintas bases de datos y mostrar la información en las vistas. Pero me di cuenta que las consultas no están trayendo todos los registros. Hice un count para comparar y efectivamente, tengo casí 2 mil registros menos cuando consulto con eloquent.

Les dejo el código de mi modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\SQL\adtb;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class admMovimientos extends Model
{
    //use HasFactory;

    protected $connection   = 'sqlsrv_adtb';
    protected $table        = 'admMovimientos';
    protected $primaryKey   = 'CIDMOVIMIENTO';

    public $timestamps      = false;
    
}
```

Mi consulta se trunca exactamente en el registro con el ID = 667300, de ahí en adelante no obtengo más registros, ni haciendo consultas en eloquent con el metodo where. Por ejemplo:

```
class admMovimientosController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        
        $movs = admMovimientos::find('667301');

        return ["movs" => $movs];
    }
}
```

Comment: No hay errores? Usas debugbar? mira el log de Laravel y el log del server.

Comment: Y no has probado con usar directamente una query SQL??

Answer (score 0):

Para localizar un solo registro intenta con:

```html
$movs = admMovimientos::select()->whereid(667301)->first();
```

o para todos

```html
$movs = admMovimientos::select()->get();

o

$movs = admMovimientos::all();
```

Si no es lo que buscas tal vez un poco más de código sería funcional, igual te recomiendo usar debugbar para ver la conversión del ORM a la consulta sql y comprobar que ejecutandola en tu manager o server efectivamente no regrese la misma cantidad de información.

también puedes hacer un dd para ver que te devuelve la variable

```html
dd($movs);
```

Comment: Ya intenté haciendo eso, pero sin resultados desde eloquent por ejemplo. Si ejecuto estas consultas con el whereid, me trae resultado si pongo el ID 667300 pero no con el 667301 y ambos existen la base de datos. ¿será que están truncando las consultas?

Comment: Consulte directamente en sql server y tengo un total de 655128 registros y con eloquent solo me trae un total de 633253